# I can not find the element (input tag) on the page

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to enter username and password to login to my bank account by VBA. I can find the password Input Tag to enter the password, but cannot find the userform Input Tag at all. I tried the following methods one by one, but none of the Find methods worked and there is no other attributes for this tag which I can look for

```
Dim Mybrowser As New WebDriver
Set Mybrowser = New WebDriver
Mybrowser.Start "chrome"
Mybrowser.Get "https://tbconline.ge/tbcrd/login?t=false"

Mybrowser.FindElementByName("loginUsername1633281403139").SendKeys ("test")
'or
'Mybrowser.FindElementByClass("fblock100 > .ng-valid").SendKeys ("test")
'or
'Mybrowser.FindElementByCss("css=.fblock100 > .ng-valid").SendKeys ("test")
'or
'Mybrowser.FindElementByXpath("//input[@name='loginUsername1633281403139']").SendKeys ("test")
'or
'Mybrowser.FindElementByName("loginPassword1633282058600")
```

Am I making a mistake in the code ? or is it true that sometimes we cannot find some elements by find method on a page, although they exist there ? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name or CSS that you've used, looks brittle in nature, Probably generated by backend framework, so on every run they will change, Please use customize and optimize CSS or Xpath from below.

Note that `CSS` has more preference than `XPATH`

Please use this `css` for **username**

```
input[formcontrolname='username']
```

**xpath**

```
//input[@formcontrolname='username']
```

for password field :

**css**

```
input[formcontrolname='password']
```

**xpath**

```
//input[@formcontrolname='password']
```

You can learn [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) from here.

Comment: I am very grateful, cruisepandey. yes it is working now, I checked the element tag by inspect and also recorded by selenium IDE but none of them talked about your attributes, or maybe they did but i did not understand them. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` attribute value `loginUsername1633281403139` seems to be dynamic so always use some static attributes to find elements or write reliable `xpaths`.  Please see below different ways to find elements.

**UserName**:

`CSS`     : `input[name*='loginUsername']`

`xPath#1` : `//input[@formcontrolname='username']`

`xPath#2` : `//input[starts-with(@name,'loginUsername')]`

`xPath#3` : `//input[@ng-reflect-name='username']`

---

**Password**:

`CSS`     : `input[name*='loginPassword']`

`xPath#1` : `//input[@formcontrolname='password']`

`xPath#2` : `//input[starts-with(@name,'loginPassword')]`

`xPath#3` : `//input[@ng-reflect-name='password']`

I would suggest you to practice with finding locators. Please go through this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) it will helps you.